# What are the errors here?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class program4
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.println(" Hello and welcome to the program ");
System.out.println("Enter your number.");



int number = input.nextInt();
int integerDoubled; 


System.out.println("Your result is" + doubleNumber(number));
System.out.println(" thank you for using my program ");
}

public static int doubleNumber (int x){
int integerDoubled;
return integerDoubled  = (x*2);

}

if (integerDoubled < 100 ); {
less_100(integerDoubled);

} else if ; 

greater_100(integerDoubled);



public static int less_100 (int integerDoubled)
{
   int integerDoubled;
  return integerDoubled =(x*2);
  } 
 public static int greater_100 (int integerDoubled) 
 {
  int integerDoubled;
    return integerDoubled =(x*3);
   }


}
    }
```

I think the error is in the If statement but i don't know how to fix it.
I know integerDoubled is a local variable and i should make it global but I'm not sure how to do that. should i put the if statement together with the doubleNumber function??

Comment: you can't have an if statement in the middle of your class - it must be in a method.

Comment: Your main problem is indentation, currently your code is very unreadable. If you would let your IDE handle formatting for you, many problems would be visible at first glance.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `if else` it returns values to nowhere ?

Answer (score 0):

If you formatted your code (your IDE will do this for you), you would see that the `if` statement is not inside a method as it must be.  If you use your IDE correctly, finding and correcting such error would be much faster and you barely have to think about it.

Comment: I was using NetBeans to fix the code but maybe ill try IDE, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make sense of your program this is what I came up with

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class T
{   

    public static int doubleNumber (int x){
        int integerDoubled;
        return integerDoubled  = (x*2);
    }



    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println(" Hello and welcome to the program ");
        System.out.println("Enter your number.");



        int number = input.nextInt();
        int integerDoubled=doubleNumber(number); 


        System.out.println("Your result is" + integerDoubled);
        System.out.println(" thank you for using my program ");
        if (integerDoubled < 100 ) {
            less_100(integerDoubled);

        } 
        else
            greater_100(integerDoubled);
    }






    public static int less_100 (int integerDoubled)
    {

        return integerDoubled =(integerDoubled*2);
    } 
    public static int greater_100 (int integerDoubled) 
    {

        return integerDoubled =(integerDoubled*3);
    }



}
```

Comment: the program is supposed to double the value entered and then check if the result is: 1)less than a 100 it would double it again but if the result is 2) bigger than 100 it would triple it. i know my code was badly written so the purpose was not clear, ill try to edit the code you wrote and thank you for your help.